# ng-class not showing correct

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have form where when is $isvalidate = true, the button has class 'disable-reg-btn', like this:

```
ng-class="{{reg_form.$invalid ? 'disable-reg-btn' : ''}}"
```

, but when I see page in the browser and when the form is invalid I see in Dev tools in Chrome this:

```
<button ng-class="disable-reg-btn" ng-disabled="true" ......
```

and the class is not added.
Where is the error ?

I am using Angular 1.5.8.
Angular is added in the footer.
The button is within the div with ng-app and ng-controller attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Evaluated Expression`:

```
ng-class="{'disable-reg-btn': reg_form.$invalid}"
```

Check this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) for more info.

Comment: Thx, your is the answer. I have same problem and with `ng-disabled="{{reg_form.$invalid}}"`, it render `ng-disabled="true"`, but not `disabled="disabled"` what is proper way to do this things ?

Comment: In the most of `Angular` *directives*  you shouldn't use interpolations.. so you should change to: `ng-disabled="reg_form.$invalid"`